# How to use @ConversationScoped with Ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, cdi, conversation-scope

I'm using JSF2 and PrimeFaces and each time I make an Ajax request and check if the current `conversation` is transient, it isn't and a new conversation is started.

When I disable the Ajax request, the form automatically passes the `cid` and the conversation is resumed, but when the is an Ajax request, the `cid`isn't passed automatically.

How is the right way to pass the `cid` when using Ajax requests with `@ConversationScoped`? Why this parameter isn't passed automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really clear on what your use-case is; but in theory, you could pass the parameter using the `<f:attribute/>` tag on any given component.

1. Add the `<f:attribute/>` tag to the component initiating the AJAX call

   ```
   <p:commandLink id="aComponent" value="#{bean.val}" action="#{bean.doSomething}">
      <f:attribute name="conversationId" value="#{param['cid']}"/>           
   </p:commandLink>
   ```
2. You can pull the parameter from the component's parameter map in your backing bean:

   ```
   FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   UIViewRoot theView = context.getViewRoot();
   UIComponent component = theView.findComponent("aComponent");
   Integer theConversationId =(Integer) component.getAttributes().get("cid");
   ```

The key point here is that the parameter is available in the `#{param}` map (as any other `GET` parameter). The reason why it's not automatically transmitted via ajax is just that: GET parameters require a full HTTP request to be transmitted. The whole point of AJAX is that you can pick and choose what to send to the server.